# spring framework built-in html/css/javascript output encoding?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Does spring framework have built-in html/css/javascript output encoding feature? I tried to search but couldn't find it.

Please advise.
thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean a templating engine for generating HTML from code? Spring MVC supports [several options for web-based views](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/view.html) including [Thymeleaf](http://www.thymeleaf.org/)

Comment: What is the syntax for doing output encoding in a string in the templating engine? For example, `<td th:text="${prod.name}">Oranges</td>` Just to clarify, output encoding of a string, css, javascript will be done on the templating engine, or in the spring code? Thanks!!

Comment: The syntax depends on which method from that documentation you choose. I haven't actually used them myself